# q - defer resolving before a value is defined only when used in .then() chains

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, resolve

I'm new to promises and I feel like I'm doing this right however Im getting `null` or `undefinded` returned trying to return values down my promise chain (using the `q` lib)

Right now I am using a less sophisticated approach grabbing each returned value like so

```
_data.parser(user_request)
 .then(function(parsedRequest) {

    setOptions(parsedRequest);

 }).fail(function(error) {
    console.log("Error Parsing Users Request: ", error);
});
```

and using it in another function like so

```
function setOptions(parsedRequest) {
 _options.setEtag(parsedRequest.fullurl) <----when I add this to a promise chain 
}
```

like this:

```
_data.parser(u_req).then(function(parsedRequest) {
        return _options.setEtag(parsedRequest.fullurl) <--- this returns null/undefined
    }).then(function(parsedRequest) {
        console.log("parsedRequest: ", parsedRequest);
        return _options.setHeaders(parsedRequest.fullurl, etag)
    }).then(function(headers) {
```

where the function its getting hung up on looks like the following

```
setEtag: function(fullurl, callback) {
        console.log("fullurl: ", fullurl);           <--- logs the path ok
        var deferred = q.defer();
        if(fullurl) {

      etagRef.child(fullurl).child('id').once("value", function(snapshot) {

      deferred.resolve(snapshot.val()); <--- HERE ITS RESOLVING BEFORE ITS DEFINED
            })
        } else {
            deferred.reject(new Error("Could not create etag "));
        }
        deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

what would case this line:

```
deferred.resolve(snapshot.val());
```

to return `undefined` when I use the `.then()` chain and not when Im calling it to another function?

Comment: What is the log from running this code? Is the `console.log("parsedRequest:...")` line ever invoked?

Comment: yes, when it gets there it logs as `null` does it look like im on the right track?

Comment: Your code doesn't look to have any problems to me. Make sure snapshow.val() is actually returning something.

Comment: The line `deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);` will throw when no `callback` is passed.